# How to set value of progress bar

Tags: c#, winforms, progress-bar

I have written a user control using C# Winforms. In the user control, I have three textboxes:

- txtStartNumber - input is of type: int.
- txtEndNumber  - input is of type: int.
- txtQuantity - iput is of type: int. (value = txtEndNumber - txtStartNumber)

The progress bar denotes the no. of records added to the database and its total range is set to be equal to txtQuantity.

When one or more records are duplicate, the progress bar is stopped.

My questions are:

1. How to set the initial value of the progress bar?
2. How to manage the progress shown by progress bar?

How I save it to the database:

```
for (long i = from; i < to; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < (to - from); j++)
    {
        arrCardNum[j] = from + j;
        string r = arrCardNum[j].ToString();
        try
        {
            sp.SaveCards(r, 2, card_Type_ID, SaveDate, 2);
            progressBar1.Value = j;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm afriad I can't quite understand what your problem is. Can you give some example code (or a simplified version that highlights your problem?)

Comment: Well... the problem could come from a lot of place! How do you fill your database, a background thread? Where do you get your progress info?

Comment: when button clicked, record are saved.here i want to set progress bar that is filled.

Comment: lightStriker, i don't understand what you said?

Comment: in for loop, that save record: for (long i = from; i < to; i++)
             {
                 for (int j = 0; j < (to - from); j++)
                 {
                     arrCardNum[j] = from + j;
                     string r = arrCardNum[j].ToString();
                     try
                     {
                         sp.SaveCards(r, 2, card_Type_ID, SaveDate, 2);
                         progressBar1 .Value = e.ProgressPercentage; 
                     }

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
private void StartBackgroundWork() {
    if (Application.RenderWithVisualStyles)
        progressBar.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Marquee;
    else {
        progressBar.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Continuous;
        progressBar.Maximum = 100;
        progressBar.Value = 0;
        timer.Enabled = true;
    }
    backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
}

private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    progressBar.Value += 5;
    if (progressBar.Value > 120)
        progressBar.Value = 0;
}
```

The Marquee style requires VisualStyles to be enabled, but it continuously scrolls on its own without needing to be updated.  I use that for database operations that don't report their progress.

Here is another [Progress Bar Tutorial](http://www.dotnetperls.com/progressbar)

Comment: @user1770370 Close the Form that has the loading bar. To stop a second thread  use Thead.Join()

Answer (score 0):

You can't use loop to do this with progressbar. There is a difference between running code in for, while, do...while loops or in timers. In loops code is immediately done and you can't see this, in timers you can. Even if you try to put in loops if counters, it will not works:

```
for(int i=a;i<b;++i)
{
    if (cnt < 1000000)
    {
        IncrProgressBar();
        cnt++;
    }
    else
    {
        cnt = 0;
    }
}
```

If you want to use progressbar to do this then you must put in timer OnTick event code that adds data to database, and in this event increment progressbar value. It's similarly with changing form component's other properties (Text, Size, ...). If you want to see change on component you must use timers.

Answer (score 0):

To change the value use:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar2.Value = progressBar2.Value - 15;
    }
```

In C#